# How to create an installer for a project generating PROLOG code?

Tags: java, swing, prolog, inno-setup

I'm creating a project that generates a prolog file that will be audited by swi prolog using the old java swing, how can I create an installer that packs jar files and prolog compiler together?
So that the user no more needs to install SWI prolog separately

This is how the project runs in development:

1- install swi prolog (in my case it was with an exe)

2- create a swing program that generates prolog code

3-  this program write the prolog code in a separate file, created by the java swing file writer.

4- Add a jar file that links the swing program to swi prolog

The file in step 3 is audited by swi prolog through the jar library

and response from swi pass through this jar library.

then these response are displayed in the program.

Comment: That's too broad to me. The way your question is posted, you will need someone with both [tag:prolog] and [tag:inno-setup] knowledge. You may have problems finding someone to answer such question. – If you tell us step-by-step, what does installing prolog and your jar files involve, we can help you implementing that in Inno Setup.

Comment: First you need to know clearly how your application and its dependencies can be installed on a clean machine manually, and then any installer technology (Inno Setup or not) is just there to automate the steps. Up-to-now, I cannot tell if you know the manual steps yet and if the answer is no you should go back and learn more about your own app.